# Transfer not invoking

Tags: anchor, solana-program, transfer

I'm trying to implement transfer in my multisignature wallet, and I've created a transfer function that checks if the transaction has enough approvals and then the program should send the transaction, but for some reason, the transfer is not executing. The whole function executes without errors, but the balance is not changing in any of the accounts.

````
 pub fn execute_transfer_transaction(ctx: Context<ExecuteTransferTransaction>) -> Result<()> {
        msg!("Executing Transaction");
        if ctx.accounts.transaction.did_execute {
            return Err(ErrorCode::AlreadyExecuted.into());
        }

       if ctx.accounts.transaction.deleted {
                return Err(ErrorCode::TransactionIsDeleted.into());
            }

        let sig_count = ctx
            .accounts
            .transaction
            .signers
            .iter()
            .filter(|&did_sign| *did_sign)
            .count() as u64;
        if sig_count < ctx.accounts.wallet.threshold {
            return Err(ErrorCode::NotEnoughSigners.into());
        }

        let amount_of_lamports = ctx.accounts.transaction.value;
        let from = ctx.accounts.from.to_account_info();
        let to = ctx.accounts.to.to_account_info();

        if from.key() != ctx.accounts.transaction.from || from.key() != ctx.accounts.transaction.to{
            return Err(ErrorCode::ForbiddenRecipientManipulation.into());
        }
        
        if **from.try_borrow_lamports()? < amount_of_lamports {
            return Err(ErrorCode::InsufficientFundsForTransaction.into());
        }
        msg!("Transfering {} lamports from {} to {}", amount_of_lamports, from.key(), to.key());

        **from.try_borrow_mut_lamports()? -= amount_of_lamports;
        **to.try_borrow_mut_lamports()? += amount_of_lamports;
        ctx.accounts.transaction.did_execute = true;

        emit!(TransferExecutedEvent {
            wallet: ctx.accounts.wallet.key(),
            transaction: ctx.accounts.transaction.key(),
            from: from.key(),
            to: to.key(),
            amount: ctx.accounts.transaction.value,
        });

        Ok(())
    }
    ```
````

Comment: You'll only be able to debit lamports if (in your case) your program OWNS the account its debiting from. Who is the owner of this account: `let from = ctx.accounts.from.to_account_info();`

Comment: Is is debitting from account owned by a program, debit account in this case is wallet created by wallet. And the function runs without throwing error, in case of account not being owned by program it would throw an error right?

Comment: Yes, so if you want this function to be universal, you'll have to check who the owner of the account is. if its a system owned account, use the system program transfer instruction (you'll require the debitor to be a signer)

Comment: In my app it is always program owned account and when invoking it in stand alone function, it transfer sol as expected. But when it is wrapped in this execute_transfer_function it is for some reason not transfering sol, but returns `Ok(())` anyway without throwing any errors, which is very strange for me.

Comment: Oh, strange, can you share the call site of the function

Answer (score 1):

Since there are no errors then it's very likely that this is because your account isn't specified to have the `account(mut)` attribute. Adding `mut` should fix it.